# Changing file name causing exceptions

Tags: java, android, file-management

I am changing the string constant of a file name from InternalString to Location. This is causing the following errors:

12-01 12:58:47.555: W/System.err(6405): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.example.app3/files/Location: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

code causing error:

String FILENAME = "Location";

```
try {
    InputStream fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
    byte[] dataArray = new byte[fis.available()];
    while (fis.read(dataArray) != -1)
    {
        String text = new String(dataArray);
        tvCoordinates = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvcoordinates);
        tvCoordinates.setText(text);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: code does not match exception.

Comment: I have arranged it excuse me as I was testing with several strings

Comment: this file apparently does not exist. Did you create it?

Comment: no I did not add any file. Is it possible that it creates it automatically or it is overwriting some file that already exists?

Comment: what would you expect to read from a file that does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /data/data/com.example.app3/files/**InternalLocation**

For one thing, *InternalLocation != Location*.

For another...does the file exist in this location already?

Comment: location does not exist. This said I did not create InternalString neither. Is it created automatically?

Comment: Not by trying to read it, only if you are writing to it. If you attempt to read a missing file you will get a FileNotFoundException.